# Explain this convergence among Pythagorean triplets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Why do the ratios of successive values of integers $a$ and $c$, where $a^{2}+(a+1)^{2}=c^{2}$, appear to converge to
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}},\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}\rightarrow3+2\sqrt{2}$$

I rigorously generated all the {a,c} pairs where $a^{2}+(a+1)^{2}=c^{2}$ for $a<10^6$:

{3, 5}, {20, 29}, {119, 169}, {696, 985}, {4059, 5741}, {23660, 33461}, {137903, 195025}, {803760, 1136689}...

We can see that the fit to the ratio just gets better and better...

$$\frac{c_{8}}{c_{7}}=\frac{1136689}{195025}\approx5.82842712473...$$

$$3+2\sqrt{2}\approx5.82842712475... $$

Why does this ratio emerge? And with no other pairs between that satisfy the condition?

Comment: Something to do will Pell's equation, no doubt.

Comment: Have you measured how good this observation is at actually predicting next solutions?

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A001652

Comment: $3+2\sqrt{2}$ is one root of $x^2-6x+1$ and in fact the $c_n$ satisfy the relation $$c_{n+2}=6c_{n+1}-c_n$$ And the $a_n$ apparently satisfy $$a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n+2$$ This should be the key for the explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
a^{2}+(a+1)^{2}&=c^{2} \\
2a^2+2a+1&=c^2 \\
2\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 +\frac{1}{2}&=c^2 \\
(2a+1)^2+1&=2c^2 \\
2c^2-(2a+1)^2&=1 \\
2c^2-d^2&=1 \quad | \quad d=2a+1
\end{align}$$

The above pell equation:  $2c^2-d^2=1$ factors into $(c\sqrt 2-d)(c\sqrt 2 +d)=1$.  With the initial solution being $(c_0,d_0)=(1,1)$, we have that $(\sqrt 2-1)(\sqrt 2 +1)=1$.  Since we are permitted to multiply any equation by a constant we choose $(\sqrt 2-1)^2(\sqrt 2 +1)^2=(3-2\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt 2)=1^2=1$.  Doing this results in

$$\begin{align}
(c\sqrt 2-d)(3-2\sqrt 2)(c\sqrt 2 +d)(3+2\sqrt 2)&=1 \\
&\implies \\
2(3c+2d)^2-(4c+3d)^2&=1
\end{align}$$

This allows you to show iterative solutions:

$$\begin{cases}
c_{k+1}=3c_k+2d_k \\
d_{k+1}=4c_k+3d_k
\end{cases}$$

Which can be solved by the method I outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2401763/419507) to produce:

$$c_k=\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4} \left(3+2\sqrt 2\right)^k+\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{4} \left(3-2\sqrt 2\right)^k$$

note that the effect of $(3-2\sqrt 2)^k$ diminishes with increasing k, explaining your observation

Comment: Wow!  Thank you, not just for the answer but for the excellent explanation!

Comment: @JerryGuern thanks bud.  Some of the janitors don't like it when you render things clearly, but I much prefer it that way....

Comment: Excellent explanation, but note that for this to be a complete solution one step is missing: proving that this algorithm produces *all* solutions to the initial equation, and not only some of them.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni in all honesty I'm stumped as to how to do that

Comment: The usual trick is: each solution is associated to a power of $(\sqrt{2}+1)^k = c_k\sqrt{2}+d_k$; let $c,d$ a hypothetical solution outside of your "main sequence", with $c_k < c < c_{k+1}$. Then, $(c\sqrt{2}+d) / (c_k\sqrt{2}+d_k)$ produces a solution that is smaller than the minimal solution $(c_0, d_0)$, contradiction. (One also needs to prove that $c_0=d_0=1$ is the minimal solution, but that is trivial in this case).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ahh yes... Thank you.   May be including that in an upcoming edit

Comment: I generalized this result to {a,a+n,c} in an Answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The sequence $a_n$ is https://oeis.org/A001652.

This sequence is defined by $$\cases{a_n=6a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2\\ a_0=0\\a_1=3}$$

Therefore the ratio $r_n={a_n\over a_{n-1}}$ has limit $3+2\sqrt 2$ as observed by Klaus Brockhaus. I'll add a proof later.

Answer (score 3):

The equation $a^2+(a+1)^2=c^2$ is equivalent to
$$
(2a+1)^2+1=2c^2\tag1
$$
That is, $\frac{2a+1}c$ is a close under-approximation to $\sqrt2$. In fact, it can be shown that if
$$
\left|\,\frac pq-r\,\right|\le\frac1{2q^2}\tag2
$$
then $\frac pq$ is a [continued fraction convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) for $r$. From $(1)$, we get
$$
\left(\sqrt2-\frac{2a+1}c\right)\left(\sqrt2+\frac{2a+1}c\right)=\frac1{c^2}\tag3
$$
From $(3)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt2-\frac{2a+1}c\right)\sqrt2
&\le\left(\sqrt2-\frac{2a+1}c\right)\left(\sqrt2+\frac{2a+1}c\right)\\
&=\frac1{c^2}\\[3pt]
&\le1\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\frac{2a+1}c\ge\sqrt2-\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and therefore $\sqrt2+\frac{2a+1}c\ge2\sqrt2-\frac1{\sqrt2}\gt2$. Applying $(3)$ again, we get that
$$
\left|\,\frac{2a+1}c-\sqrt2\,\right|\le\frac1{2c^2}\tag5
$$
Thus, we see that $\frac{2a+1}c$ must be a convergent for $\sqrt2$.

---

If $\frac{2a+1}c$ is a convergent for $\sqrt2$, then it can be shown that
$$
\left|\,\frac{2a+1}c-\sqrt2\,\right|\le\frac1{2c^2}\tag6
$$
If $\frac{2a+1}c\lt\sqrt2$, then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt2-\frac{2a+1}c\right)\left(\sqrt2+\frac{2a+1}c\right)
&\le\frac1{2c^2}\left(2\sqrt2+\frac1{2c^2}\right)\\
2c^2-(2a+1)^2&\le\sqrt2+\frac1{4c^2}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
which means that $a$ and $c$ satisfy $(1)$.

---

Thus, $(1)$ is satisfied precisely when $\frac{2a+1}c$ is a continued fraction convergent for $\sqrt2$ which is an under-estimate with odd numerator.

---

The continued fraction for $\sqrt2$ is $(1;\overline{2})$, so the convergents start
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
&&1&2&2&2&2&\cdots\\\hline
0&1&\color{#C00}{1}&3&\color{#C00}{7}&17&\color{#C00}{41}&\cdots\\\hline
1&0&\color{#C00}{1}&2&\color{#C00}{5}&12&\color{#C00}{29}&\cdots
\end{array}\tag8
$$
Because of the repetition of the continued fraction after the first term, the recurrence for the numerators and denominators for $n\ge1$ is
$$
x_n=2x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}\tag9
$$
From this recurrence we get that all the numerators will be odd. It is a fact about continued fractions that convergents oscillate above and below the target limit, so that we only look at the convergents with even index: $1,\frac75,\frac{41}{29},\ldots$. Using $(9)$, we can derive the recurrence for every other numerator and denominator:
$$
x_n=6x_{n-2}-x_{n-4}\tag{10}
$$
This is the recurrence for the even indexed numerators and denominators from $(8)$; and thus, the possible values of $2a+1$ and $c$ from $(1)$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
2a_n+1&1&7&41&239&\cdots\\\hline
c_n&1&5&29&169&\cdots
\end{array}\tag{11}
$$
where both $2a_n+1$ and $c_n$ satisfy the recurrence
$$
x_n=6x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}\tag{12}
$$
Solutions to the [linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) in $(12)$ are linear combinations of $\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n$ and $\left(3-\sqrt8\right)^n$:
$$
\begin{align}
2a_n+1&=\frac{1+\sqrt2}2\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n+\frac{1-\sqrt2}2\left(3-\sqrt8\right)^n\tag{13}\\
c_n&=\frac{2+\sqrt2}4\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n+\frac{2-\sqrt2}4\left(3-\sqrt8\right)^n\tag{14}
\end{align}
$$
$(13)$ gives the formula
$$
a_n=-\frac12+\frac{1+\sqrt2}4\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n+\frac{1-\sqrt2}4\left(3-\sqrt8\right)^n\tag{15}
$$
As $n\to\infty$, $(14)$ and $(15)$ become asymptotically
$$
\begin{align}
a_n&\sim\frac{1+\sqrt2}4\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n\tag{16}\\
c_n&\sim\frac{2+\sqrt2}4\left(3+\sqrt8\right)^n\tag{17}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental, from the OP:

I generalized AmateurMathPirate's answer to arbitrary $a,a+n,c$:

$$a=\frac{n}{4}\left(\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^{k}+\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^{k}\right)-\frac{n}{2}$$

$$b=a+n $$

$$c=\frac{n}{4}\left(\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^{k}+\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^{k}\right)$$

It's easy to prove that $a,b,c$ are a triple for any choice of positive $n,k$

This form doesn't cover all triplets, for example {5,12,13}.

And for the record, I only figured out this relation after I read AmateurMathPirate's answer above.